# Storing the result of the outputfield tag in a variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, translation, translation-workbench

I need to store the result of the outputfield in a visualforce variable. I have an object that has a picklist value that is translated into several languages(translation workbench). When the picklist field is output using the apex:outputfield tag, the picklist value gets translated into the language that is set in the visualforce page, something like below:

```
 <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Phase__c}" lang="es"/>
```

My issue is that all the picklist values on the field Phase__c have a weird prefix, for example, d.phase1, g.phase1, h.phase1. My idea is to keep the result of the apex:outputfield in a apex:variable and then using the SUBSTITUTE function to get rid of the weird prefix. I cannot use javascript because everything is done in an email template.

I tried the following but does not work:

```
<apex:variable var="phase" value='<apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Phase__c}" lang="es"/>' />
```

**How can I accomplish this?**

Comment: in salesforce picklist values is automatically translate. also for output field i got same picklist values as per selected on opportunity record no prefix showing on my side. can you please share your full code and database records of picklist screen.
so i can help you more. <p>
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"> <apex:pageBlock > <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity.Status__c}" lang="es"/> </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page> </p>

Comment: did you try using `<apex:variable var="phase" value="{!Opportunity.Phase__c}/>` ?

Comment: Have you tried using outputText instead of outputField? OutputText has the lang attribute and allows you to use formula's in the value tag. You should than be-able to use the substitution trick like you wanted to. Unfortunately, I don't have the translation workbench set up so I can't test it.

Comment: I need to use apex:outputField because it translates the picklist value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once and came up with this nasty solution:

TranslateValueController:

```
public class TranslateValueController {

    public String objectName {get; set;}
    public String objectId {get; set;}
    public String fieldName {get; set;}
    public String lang {get; set;}

    public SObject obj {get; private set;}
    public Object fieldValue {get; private set;}

    public TranslateValueController() {
        objectId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('objectId');
        objectName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('objectName');
        fieldName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('fieldName');
        lang = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lang');

        String query = 'SELECT '+ fieldName + ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE ID = \'' + objectId + '\'';
        obj = Database.query(query)[0];

        fieldValue = obj.get(fieldName);
    }   
}
```

TranslateValuePage:

```
<apex:page controller="TranslateValueController" 
           language = "{!lang}"  
           showHeader="false" 
           sidebar="false"      
           standardStylesheets="false">

    <apex:outputField value="{!obj[fieldName]}"/>

</apex:page>
```

ValueTranslator:

```
public class ValueTranslator {

    public static String translate(String objectName, String objectId, String fieldName, String lang){
        Pagereference r = new PageReference('/apex/TranslateValuePage?objectName='+ objectName +'&objectId=' + objectId + '&fieldName=' + fieldName + '&lang=' + lang);
        String pageContent = r.getContent().toString();

        Integer spanStart = pageContent.indexOf('<span');
        Integer spanEnd = pageContent.indexOf('</span>') + '</span>'.length();

        String span = pageContent.substring(spanStart, spanEnd);

        Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
        doc.load(span);
        return doc.getRootElement().getText();
    }
}
```

You can get the translated value in your controller by invoking:

```
ValueTranslator.translate('Opportunity', 'e4u8E6jt00wcgMqQope', 'Phase__c', 'es');
```

And then use it in your VF page.

Comment: This solution will not work because, as mentioned, it is required to get the apex:outputfield in an email template, in your solution is used PageReference which is a callout. Salesforce does not allow a call-out inside a call-out. Thank you for trying anyways.